# Upgrade SATA connection on MBP 3,1

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, sata

When replacing my HDD in my MBP 3,1 with a SSD (SATA3), I noticed that the SATA1 cable can be fully removed.

Thus I thought, that it might be possible to **replace the SATA 1 cable by a SATA 3** cable in order to boost my SSD use.

However, I do not know whether this is *supported by the Logicboard*... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best suggestion is that you try. Worst case it will downscale to SATA1/2 speed if it's all it can handle.

The easiest way to determine if your board will support the speed of SATA3 is to have a look at your Serial ATA settings in system information and check your link speed. It will show the supported speed and negotiated speed.

I have a MBP 6,2 which does support SATA3 on the board. I know my MB 3,1 only support SATA1, however it was always a low spec model compared to the MBP range and it may have been limited to save cost.

[image: Link Speed]

Comment: Thanks. Well, I checked... mine also supports only 1.5 gigabit.

Comment: @Matt yes, only recent models started to support the new SATA. My Macbook Air mid-2011 does have it.